# Concatenate Grouped Columns with dplyr to make a unique key

Tags: r, dplyr

I will work with mtcars to make this reproducible.

I am trying to make a function that will allow me to create a concatenated unique identified (key) with the grouped variable. This is needed for easy indexing when i move the output into excel.

Here is my grouped data frame. *I added AdditionalVar since dplyr will drop the last grouped variable.

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
mutate(AdditionalVar = "AddVar") %>% 
group_by(cyl,gear,carb,AdditionalVar) %>% 
summarise(avgHP = mean(hp)) 


# Groups:   cyl, gear, carb [?]
     cyl  gear  carb AdditionalVar avgHP
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
 1     4     3     1 AddVar         97  
 2     4     4     1 AddVar         72.5
 3     4     4     2 AddVar         79.5
 4     4     5     2 AddVar        102  
 5     6     3     1 AddVar        108. 
 6     6     4     4 AddVar        116. 
 7     6     5     6 AddVar        175  
 8     8     3     2 AddVar        162. 
 9     8     3     3 AddVar        180  
10     8     3     4 AddVar        228  
11     8     5     4 AddVar        264  
12     8     5     8 AddVar        335
```

**My goal is to have a Conc (unique key) column which works on the grouped variables, similar to the below. i don't want to specificity the grouped variables directly as this cannot translate over to other applications without changing it.**

```
> df %>%  mutate(Conc= paste(cyl,gear,carb,sep = "`"))
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   cyl, gear, carb [12]
     cyl  gear  carb AdditionalVar avgHP Conc 
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>
 1     4     3     1 AddVar         97   4`3`1
 2     4     4     1 AddVar         72.5 4`4`1
 3     4     4     2 AddVar         79.5 4`4`2
 4     4     5     2 AddVar        102   4`5`2
 5     6     3     1 AddVar        108.  6`3`1
 6     6     4     4 AddVar        116.  6`4`4
 7     6     5     6 AddVar        175   6`5`6
 8     8     3     2 AddVar        162.  8`3`2
 9     8     3     3 AddVar        180   8`3`3
10     8     3     4 AddVar        228   8`3`4
11     8     5     4 AddVar        264   8`5`4
12     8     5     8 AddVar        335   8`5`8
```

I think the answer is to have something like the below but it's giving me the column names as the Conc instead of the data like the above.

```
> df %>%  mutate(Conc= paste0(!!group_vars(.),collapse = "`"))
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   cyl, gear, carb [12]
     cyl  gear  carb AdditionalVar avgHP Conc         
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>        
 1     4     3     1 AddVar         97   cyl`gear`carb
 2     4     4     1 AddVar         72.5 cyl`gear`carb
 3     4     4     2 AddVar         79.5 cyl`gear`carb
 4     4     5     2 AddVar        102   cyl`gear`carb
 5     6     3     1 AddVar        108.  cyl`gear`carb
 6     6     4     4 AddVar        116.  cyl`gear`carb
 7     6     5     6 AddVar        175   cyl`gear`carb
 8     8     3     2 AddVar        162.  cyl`gear`carb
 9     8     3     3 AddVar        180   cyl`gear`carb
10     8     3     4 AddVar        228   cyl`gear`carb
11     8     5     4 AddVar        264   cyl`gear`carb
12     8     5     8 AddVar        335   cyl`gear`carb
```

Comment: Maybe you just want to use `group_indices()`?

Comment: ...or just `mutate(interaction(cyl,gear,carb))`.

Comment: @joran I think the `interaction` version would miss that they want to *not* have to name the columns here, but take them with tidyeval from the set of columns that the data is grouped by. Unless you can pass `interaction` a list of quosures...?

Comment: @camille Yes, that's probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `group_map`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_map( ~ .x %>% 
                      mutate(Conc = paste(.y, collapse="`")))
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   cyl, gear, carb [12]
#     cyl  gear  carb AdditionalVar avgHP Conc 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>
# 1     4     3     1 AddVar         97   4`3`1
# 2     4     4     1 AddVar         72.5 4`4`1
# 3     4     4     2 AddVar         79.5 4`4`2
# 4     4     5     2 AddVar        102   4`5`2
# 5     6     3     1 AddVar        108.  6`3`1
# 6     6     4     4 AddVar        116.  6`4`4
# 7     6     5     6 AddVar        175   6`5`6
# 8     8     3     2 AddVar        162.  8`3`2
# 9     8     3     3 AddVar        180   8`3`3
#10     8     3     4 AddVar        228   8`3`4
#11     8     5     4 AddVar        264   8`5`4
#12     8     5     8 AddVar        335   8`5`8
```